Equivalent condition for states in an irreducible markov chain to be symmetric
I have a discrete-time Markov chain $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ such that there is a pair $(i,j)$ of distinct states that are symmetric. i.e. $$\mathbb{P}(T_j < T_i | X_0 = i) = \mathbb{P}(T_i < T_j | X_0 = j)$$where $T_i= \min\{n \geq 1 : X_n = i\}$. I want to show that if $\{X_n\}$ is irreducible and has invariant distribution $\pi$, then two states $i$ and $j$ are symmetric if and only if $\pi(i) = \pi(j)$. How would I go about this? For the forward direction, I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{E}_{i}(T_i) = \mathbb{E}_{j}(T_{j})$ which would then imply the result since in this case $\pi(i) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}_{i}(T_{i})}$ by irreducibility, however I keep getting stuck. Any help towards showing this would be greatly appreciated.
